# Does iOS have the similar function as getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity in Android?

Tags: android, ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to know the max velocity in pan gesture, and I find that there is a function named `getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity`in Android, does iOS have the similar function to get the max velocity of gesture movement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092375/how-to-determine-true-end-velocity-of-pan-gesture) answer, change code to store velocity on each change into separate variable (you need to update variable only when new value is bigger than previous) and check variable when gesture is ended.